# SCSS precompile:assets throws invalid CSS due to http url in compiled asset file

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sass

Rails 3.1.22
sass-rails 3.2 - actionpack dependency prevents upgrading

rake assets:precompile throws error in a file called admin.css.scss

Here is the compile portion where it's complaining :

```
td .current{padding-right:12px;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:right center}
td .asc{background-image:url(http://cdn3.mysite.com/assets/up_arrow-b4361e6bd6a8af6d7d60f73acca6d973.gif)}
td .desc{background-image:url(http://cdn2.mysite.com/assets/down_arrow-d4345de2e0e231338210ca20e63f302a.gif)}
#overlay{background:url(http://cdn0.mysite.com/assets/loading-c9c18d94ad7c119962ed93ca742e78b6.gif)
```

I have these files in production right now, but the last time I precompiled was probably 6+ months ago - at that time I still had the CDN in effect and can't figure out what's different.

I've tried variations before coming to SO - image-url, image-path, asset-url, asset-path, tried changing scss to css.erb and using the <%= asset_path () %> helper, I keep getting this error.  The actual error is :

Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "    http": expected ";", was "://cdn2.mysite..."

Does anyone have any idea how I can resolve this syntax error?

Comment: There is not enough information here to reproduce a problem, other than the fact that your provided code is missing a closing curly brace.

Comment: probably you need to do is this #overlay{background-image:url(http://cdn0.mysite.com/assets/loading-c9c18d94ad7c119962ed93ca742e78b6.gif)}, can you paste the exact error orcomplete .SCSS file

Answer (score -1):

The url needs to be included in a single quote '' or double quotes ""

from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url

> The url() functional notation The URI may be quoted by single or
>   double quotes. Relative URIs are allowed and are relative to the URL
>   of stylesheet (and not to the URL of the web page).

Comment: And if you look at the examples provided on the page you just linked to, you'll see that quotes are not required.  As long as the URL does not contain specific characters, quotes are optional.